# content type for templates

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, template

I need your help with providing several Word Templates in SPO. I know how to create content types with templates and how to integrate them in a document library.
But which way should I take to provide 20+ templates for one document library? Is there a way to provide several templates as a group or folder from where users can choose and still have a clear view?

Thanks for your answers.
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not supported to group or put the options in folder for the New menu. We can only choose what template to display or not by using the "**Edit New menu**" feature.

You can add the 20+ templates to a library [with one custom content type for each](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-multiple-office-templates-to-a-document-library-cde94e90-a1ba-4b94-a187-600ed68562bb), the number of which should cause no problem while loading. But if you are afraid of losing a clear view, consider splitting them into multiple libraries.